# CIFaceFeature trackingID is always coming same for multiple faces

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, camera

I want to detect multiple faces in my project. Therefore I planned to use the trackingID property of the CIFaceFure to keep the track of the face. But I found that every time it is coming same for every face.

So my problem is that how can I identify a face uniquely when multiple face are there in the video frame. I don't want to recognize the face for later purpose only detection for the current video frame. Thanks.

I am using the same code as in SqaureCam apple sample project. in iOS 6.

```
for ( CIFaceFeature *face in features ) {
    NSLog(@"face.trackingID %d",face.trackingID);
}
```

The above code is priting the same ID for every face.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, you need to make sure to specify the usage of CIDetectorTracking in the detector's options. If I remember correctly, it should look something like this:

```
NSDictionary *detectorOptions = @{CIDetectorTracking: @YES};
CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:detectorOptions];
```